# Jquery validate plugin how to add error class to label

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the jquery validate plugin and I'm trying to override it's default behavior. this is an example of my html:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="my-input>Name</label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="required" id="my-input />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

All I want the valadate to do is add the class .error to the existing label, and then remove it once the field passes validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this is the default behaviour, you just need to stop the error message being displayed on the page.  You can do this by overriding errorPlacement

```
$('form').validate({
 errorPlacement: function () { }
});
```

**EDIT.**

sorry misread the question bit - the code below works but there is probably a better way

```
$('form').validate({
    // make sure error message isn't displayed
    errorPlacement: function () { },
    // set the errorClass as a random string to prevent label disappearing when valid
    errorClass : "bob",
    // use highlight and unhighlight
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
        .addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
        .removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

the above code comes from the highlight example on the [options docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

Answer (score 3):

```
errorElement: "label",
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertBefore(element.parent().children("br"));
},
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass("error");
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass("error");
}
```